# Return key value from alternate field in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get Elastic Search to return an aggregate key based on a different document field?

We're placing both a foreign id, and the foreign name in our type, then aggregating over the id, but would like to get the name returned. Names are not unique, so they are not appropriate to aggregate over. I'm aware that they're also not necessarily unique over the record set, but would accept a name sampled from a single record of the set.

For example, say our data is regarding sales of a product. Each sale has the product id and product name associated with it.

```
// Sales
{ "product_id": 1, "product_name": "Beer", "quantity": 3, … }
{ "product_id": 1, "product_name": "Beer", "quantity": 2, … }
{ "product_id": 2, "product_name": "Wine", "quantity": 6, … }
```

Query:

```
"aggregations": {
    "product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_id"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "day": {
          "count": {
            "value_count": {
              "field": "quantity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
…
"aggregations": {
  "product": {
    "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "1",
      "doc_count": 2,
      "count": {
        "value": 5
      }
    },{
      "key": "2",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "count": {
        "value": 6
    }
    ]
  }
}
…
```

Wanted Result:

```
…
"aggregations": {
  "product": {
    "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "Beer",
      "doc_count": 2,
      "count": {
        "value": 5
      }
    },{
      "key": "Wine",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "count": {
        "value": 6
    }
    ]
  }
}
…
```

After reading the docs on scripts, I don't think this is possible, since it evaluates on the value only, and doesn't seem to have access to the entire doc (since there isn't a doc, but a set of docs).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with scripts if you use only the script attribute alone (this then has access to the entire doc). Then split it in your client: e.g.

```
"aggs": {
    "types_of": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['product_name'].value + '|' + doc['product_id'].value"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This solution looks to good to be true, how wel does this perform?

Comment: @ries I haven't used this for heavy loads but because its lucene script (and not Groovy) its compiled to bytecode

Answer (score 0):

If you have all powers over your indexation process, I'd suggest just adding a new field on your own (not analyzed), based on the product_id, and aggregating on that field instead.

I don't think (but I may be mistaken) that what you want to do is possible.

Comment: Yea, we'd thought this might be the only option for get this all in one request. Looks like we're going to take a double request route, one to get the data, then one to look up the entity names from a separate entity table.

Comment: Yes, but if possible, index the entity nalme along with the document, that way, you will need only one request. That's the philosiphy of elasticsearch, index what you need. And if it is aleady indexed .. well, réindex, if you can.

Comment: Seeing as it looks like we can't get the entity names back from ES I'm wondering if we should have them in there at all. It might be useful for other queries. The reality is that these entity names may occasionally change. It was "good enough" for it to be returned if it meant only making a single request, but with a separate request for entity names it's not required, plus we know we're always getting the most up to date entity name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a child aggregation to get the name, so your query would be something like:

```
"aggregations": {
    "product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_id"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_name"
          }
        },
        "day": {
          "count": {
            "value_count": {
              "field": "quantity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I were to do that, then I'd end up with multiple buckets if the denormalised data had changed at some point, i.e. if there were multiple values.

Comment: Yes, that will always be an issue with the data being denormalised, a 1:1 id to name mapping won't be enforced at the "database" level, and so would need to be enforced through your code.

Another alternative would be to use parent-child relationships to maintain a more normalised structure: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/

However, as it says there:

"The relational facilities that Elasticsearch provides are great for certain scenarios…but were never meant to provide the robust relational features that you expect from an RDBM."

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the question wants to return `product_name` along with the aggregation result by `product_id`.

That problem could be solved by a topHit sub-aggregation:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "product": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "product_id"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "day": {
                    "count": {
                        "value_count": {
                            "field": "quantity"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "topHits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 1,
                        "_source": false,
                        "docvalue_fields": [
                            {
                                "field": "product_name"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the result would look like (removed the unnecessary fields):

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "product": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "1",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "topHits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "fields": {
                                        "product_name": [
                                            "Beer"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "count": {
                        "value": 5
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `count` & `product_name` is in the same bucket. By that way we can link `product_name` with `count`.

Note: If `product_name` is analyzed / normalized, then the returned result would also be normalized. To avoid that, we can [create a sub-field and normalize that field instead](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).